# JSON array in localstorage not working in IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I've ran into this problem. I wanted to store an array in local storage, so I used JSON.stringify, saved it in the local storage and then parsed it -> retrieved the original array. At first it seemed to work just fine, but when I tested it in IE (11) and in Edge, it didn't  work. Every other tested browser works just fine though. I really can't find a reason behind this and nothing I found online worked. 
I would be really grateful for any help!

The entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<body>

    <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var myArray = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5"]

    localStorage.setItem("theArray", JSON.stringify(myArray));

    var retrievedArray = localStorage.getItem("theArray");
    var parsedArray = JSON.parse(retrievedArray);

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = parsedArray[0];
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you use an old HTML header and  not the current one? Might force IE in some kind of compatibility mode without `localStorage`.

Comment: Are you testing this on a local HTML file? i.e. a file:/// URL?

Comment: So what errors are thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are testing using file:///

localStorage works only with http. You can create web server and then you can test it.

Comment: This is not an answer and should be deleted. It is nothing more than a comment and you use comment blocks for those

Comment: @charlietfl this is the answer for OP.

Comment: That doesn't make it a proper SO answer, even if it was accepted

Comment: Dinesh is correct, this is a [known issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/?page=368) with Edge and as far as I can tell there has been no response from MS in over 2 years.  I would phrase it as "localStorage inexplicably doesn't work on `file:///` URLs in Edge", to be more precise, but the sentiment is correct.

Comment: Wrong link, meant to use https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8816771/